# Proving that the relation from the null set to the null set is a function

Tags: functions

How would one prove that a relation that maps the null set to the null set is a function? I tried showing that the domain of the relation is the null set, but I'm unsure of where to proceed from there.

Comment: Note that some mathematicians choose to not allow the null set as the domain of a function, to avoid this.  (I know this, because my graduate level abstract algebra professor is one such mathematician)

Answer (score 1):

The statement that it is a function is of the form

$$(\forall x,y \in \emptyset) \: P(x,y).$$

All statements of this form are vacuously true, since $x \in \emptyset$ is always false.

Answer (score 1):

A relation on $A\times B$ fails to be a function if there exists an element $x\in A$ such that there is either no $y$ for which $(x,y)$ is a member of the relation, or there is more than one such $y$. If $A$ has no elements, therefore, then no element satisfying this failure condition can exist, so any relation with $A$ empty is a function. In particular this is also true when both $A$ and $B$ are empty.